# Open the whole scrollback buffer in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, zsh, terminal-emulator

I am using alacritty. The keybinding i am using are:

```
  - { key: E,  mods: Control, mode: Vi,    action: ScrollToTop }
  - { key: E,  mods: Control, mode: Vi,    action: ToggleNormalSelection }
  - { key: E,  mods: Control, mode: Vi,    action: ScrollToBottom }
  - { key: E,  mods: Control, mode: Vi,    action: Copy }
  - { key: E,  mods: Control, mode: Vi,    action: ClearSelection  }
  - { key: E,  mods: Control, mode: Vi,    action: ToggleViMode }
```

I am also using a zsh widget like:

```
_open_clipboard_in_file() {
  xsel -b > /tmp/alacritty-codium.txt
  codium /tmp/alacritty-codium.txt
}

zle -N _open_clipboard_in_file
bindkey '^E' _open_clipboard_in_file # Copy text
```

So, now when i press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Space > Ctrl+E > Ctrl+E</kbd>, it open the whole scrollback buffer in codium (you can use your favorite code editor).

As far I understood, due to lack of modes not being evaluated ahead of time in alacritty, we have to use three keybindings instead of one.

Is there any terminal emulator which can do this with one key stroke?

Answer (score 1):

**Update edit all terminal output in vs code file**:
Here is a simple shortcut to achieve it:
First add this shortcut to your `keybindings.json` in vs code:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+a",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
      "commands": [
        {
          "command": "workbench.action.terminal.selectAll",
        },
        {
          "command": "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction"
        },
        {
          "command": "workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile"
        },
        {
          "command": "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

After that any time when in terminal press `ctrl+alt+a` to edit all terminal output in vs code newly created unsaved file.

**Update edit in terminal**:

For Vs code integrated terminal you can use command `terminal: focus accessible buffer`
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/182210#issuecomment-1546027423

It will let you navigate through output in terminal. In order to edit it in vs code I guess you can create custom command(via keybindings.json, `runCommands`) in Vs code to open buffer, select all text and open it in editor.

**Terminal multiplexer answer**:

You can use [zellij](https://zellij.dev/) with vscode set as your default editor, like this:

```bash
EDITOR=code zellij # or just set EDITOR as global environment variable
```

And then in order to edit you scrollback **just press** `CTRL+s+e`

https://zellij.dev/news/edit-scrollback-compact/

Comment: When using tmux, if you use the config `bind-key -T root C-e run-shell "tmux capture-pane -pS - > /tmp/tmux-code.txt; codium /tmp/tmux-code.txt"` then you can use Ctrl+e to view the output buffer in vscode. However, this question is about terminal emulator (not terminal multiplexer). Thumbs up for letting us know about zellij.

Comment: @AhmadIsmail updated answer for vs code :)

Comment: @AhmadIsmail also added vs code shortcut for keybindings.json, so answer is yes, there is such emulator: vs code integrated terminal, and you can specify any shortcut you want instead `ctrl+alt+a`, maybe something shorter if you want :)